# "421 4.4.2 connection dropped" for every outgoing email destination

Tags: exchange-2010

**Microsoft Exchange 2010**

Every email we attempt to send (to many different target domains) is queued and has the error...

***451 4.4.0 Primary target IP address responded with: "421 4.4.2 connection dropped due to SocketError." Attempted failover to alternate host, but that did not succeed. Either there are no alternate hosts, or delivery failed to all alternate hosts.***

This suddenly happened out of the blue and everything was fine for many months previously. The server and local network has no problems connecting to the Internet for web browsing. Plus Exchange can still receive emails externally. It is just the sending of emails.

Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried the SMTPDIAG tool?  I just used it to troubleshoot outbound email problems and it helped greatly. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11393

Comment: Using mxtoolbox website, please make sure your OUTGOING IP is not blacklisted.

Comment: Found the answer. Turned off my AVG outgoing virus scanning and it then works fine.